# How to correctly use Typescript never

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs

I was trying to test my redux store with jest and so i came across a problem

redux types:

```
export interface TypeA {
  type: typeof TYPE_A
  payload: boolean
}

export interface TypeB {
  type: typeof TYPE_B
  payload: boolean
}

export type Types =
  | TypeA
  | TypeB
```

My reducers:

```
const ReducerExample = (
  state: boolean = false,
  action: Types
): boolean => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPE_A:
      return action.payload
    case TYPE_B:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And so in jest i was trying to get my ReducerExample default:

```
expect(ReducerExample(undefined, {} as never)).toEqual(undefined)
```

But idk if `{} as never` it's ok to use here or just in functions like erros.
I've tried with `any` but eslint told me to use "never" instead

Last thing: I cant change the redux types file. The project is big! xD

Comment: How `notificationsReducer` is typed?

Comment: @zerkms I would assume that's an instance of `ReducerExample`, though it should be equal to `false` rather than `undefined`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's my very point :-)

Comment: This is just my opinion, but if a particular usage is invalid based on the type of the function, then the test shouldn't even be added, it should be considered undefined behavior.

Comment: sorry, just forgot to change

Comment: @GustavoFerri you cannot pass `undefined` as an argument to a function that accepts `boolean`. Also `{} as never` makes very little sense: the second argument should be of `Types` type.